# Can't login - no entry fields showing

Tags: users

I have a local site which i'm working on. But somehow I got logged out and now when I want to login on localhost/user I have a login page without the login fields showing. So I can't login anymore. The weird thing is that I on the same page i can navigate to 'new account' or 'new password' and on those parts the entry fiels are showing, but at the login page they are not. 
Somebody helpt get back into my site?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a layout/theming issue. See if you can find the fields with Chrome Inspector or Firebug.

If you can't, you can try this (very, very, very) dirty workaround:

Open to the /modules/system/system.module file in an editor and find the system_init() function.

Inside the function put:

```
global $user;
$user = user_load(1);
```

Every visitor will now be user 1.

Go to appearance and change your theme to Bartik.

Remove the 2 lines from the system_init().

DO NOT EVER DO THIS ONLINE! :)